# Having trouble with curl GET in PHP

Tags: php, curl, get

I'm trying to get a JSON response from a curl GET request, but have not been able to get it to work. I've tried several examples and am just not getting anything back. This is what I'm trying:

```
$Url = "http://app.whistle.com/api/dogs/132376/dailies/16955&X-Whistle-AuthToken=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";

$ch = curl_init($Url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
$httpCode = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
curl_close($ch);
echo $result;
```

Does anyone know why this isn't working?

Comment: It's returning a 401: not authorized. I guess there's more to the authentication method that you need to pass in.

Comment: you're simply assuming success. never assume success when dealing with external resources. Always assume failure, check for failure, and treat success as a pleasant surprise.  `if ($result === false) { die(curl_error($ch)); }`. if curl_exec fails, it returns boolean false, which echoes as a zero-length invisible string.

Comment: Really strange, it comes up in my browser as is. I managed to get the token using charles proxy from an iOS app on my phone, but have no idea why it ever allowed this url to show in my mac browser,as is, in the first place (and still does).  Obviously this gives me a place to start looking.  Thanks.

Comment: Is your question answered? If so, can you mark it as answered?

Answer (score 0):

The url returns a HTTP 401 status (not authorised). This means that the authentication failed. You should check your authentication parameters. Check if you need to set username and password, or that your AuthToken is valid.

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "$username:$password");
```

Answer (score 0):

You seem to add `X-Whistle-AuthToken` to the URL. First of all, that would be done, starting with `?` since it's the first parameter, not with `&`.

Secondly since this `X-Whistle-AuthToken` starts with an `X-` I assume that it is a HTTP header that needs to be send as a HTTP header using CURL, not as a HTTP GET parameter. *But you have to check the corresponding documentation to make sure how the API expects your answer.*

Something like this will probably work as it should:

```
$Url = "http://app.whistle.com/api/dogs/132376/dailies/16955";

$ch = curl_init($Url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("X-Whistle-AuthToken: 214cca48930110a634cfc34fe9b4ee17"));

$result = curl_exec($ch);
if ($result === false){ die(curl_error($ch)); }

$httpCode = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
curl_close($ch);
var_dump($result);
```

**Last but not least:**

Change your AuthToken. You just leaked a private token that should probably stay private.